# Access controller of another application in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have some SAPUI5 applications in one SAP server. All the applications will be deployed in an ERP Server Version 6.0.

All the applications has a access url in our ERP server that can be retrieved through the SAP NetWeaver. All the urls have the format `commonPart/applicationName/index.html`. All of these application will be accessible through a Fiori launchpad application.

Now I have a controller that has to be shared between all my applications. Is there any method that I can share this controller without copy and past?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a reusable library project for SAP Fiori applications. Put your BaseController in that library. Then import the library in your application project and extend your application controller from BaseController.

Define library.js in root folder of your base project

```
sap.ui.define(["jquery.sap.global",
            "sap/ui/core/library"], // library dependency
function(jQuery) {

    "use strict";
    // delegate further initialization of this library to the Core
    sap.ui.getCore().initLibrary({
        name: "mylibrary.reuse",
        version: "1.0",
        dependencies: ["sap.ui.core"],
        types: [],
        interfaces: [],
        controls: [],
        elements: [],
        noLibraryCSS: true
    });

    return mylibrary.reuse;

}, /* bExport= */ true);
```

Declare the BaseController within it's JS file

```
 jQuery.sap.declare("mylibrary.reuse.BaseController");
 /** Controller Definition **/
```

Define and expose entry points to your library in neo-app.json

```
 {
   "routes": [{
    "path": "/resources/mylibrary/reuse",
    "target": {
        "type": "application",
        "name": "myreuselibrary",
        "entryPath": "/mylibrary/reuse"
    },
    "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
},
```

}

Then import the above library in application project, do JQuery.require() got BaseController and then extend it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You said 'Declare the BaseController within it's JS file' What does `it` refers to? We have to define BaseController within what?

Comment: Also it is not clear what is the relation between BaseController and library.js if they defined within a same project?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a BaseController which has all of the functions that you want both controllers to have, and put this js file in a public/shared folder. Then, you can extend this controller from both applications.

Comment: I did that but then I can not access the file because of cross reference error in the browser.

Comment: Just one approach that may be works but I don't know have to that, it is possible to deploy a theme and access it in bootstrapping. that was explained here https://help.hana.ondemand.com/theme_designer/frameset.htm?706af4ea51ed4c07b5b9159bf7df6471.html
If we could do the same for a js file it world be very nice.

Comment: If you host the shared file on the same server, I think you do not have to run into XSS errors and the likes. You might need domain relaxation to create matching domains/origins, as they might differ slightly. What exact error are you getting?

Comment: the problem is that I have http address of the js file while the website runs under https and it says you are not allowed access the js file in unsafe way. While SAPUI5 access it in unsafe way itself without any error.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply type in the following

`sap.ui.controller([your namespace].[controller folder name].[controller name]).[your method name]([parameters you want to pass])`

for example

`sap.ui.controller(CafApp.controller.create).onCreate(url);`