# How can we manipulate `neo-app.json` programmatically?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How can I define a new entry for `routes` part of the `neo-app.json` file in run time in an `SAPUI5` application? For example inside of the `Component.js`.

For example I want to add the following entry to the file, or add some code to `Component.js` file that has same effect like to have this entry statically in `neo-app.json`:

```
{
  "path": "/myapp",
  "target": {
    "type": "application",
    "name": "myapp"
  },
  "description": "external application"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you cannot manipulate neo-app.json from your app, as the file is owned by Web IDE. At the same time you can register resource search path via to functions:
[jQuery.sap.registerModulePath](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.registerModulePath) and 
[jQuery.sap.registerResourcePath](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.registerResourcePath)

Comment: Can you provide further explanation by providing an example that which one of these files are suitable for my case? I deployed an  application in HCP and based on the explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068639/access-controller-of-another-application-in-sapui5 , I could access a file in `myapp` inside of another application. Now I want to do that without any static modification of `neo-app.json`. But the functions that you provided seems to be irrelevant to this usecase.

Comment: I have to mentioned that I used `registerModulePath` in Component.js file. But the problem is that if I remove the entry from `neo-app.json` then by using these functions also can not access the files inside of the `myApp`.

Comment: If you want to use a shareable app then why you want to avoid using neo-app? I thought it is the right place to put all the possible routes to your shareable resources. 
As for these 2 functions I just saw them used in debugger when trying to play with shareable library and thought these should be the right functions to update resource routes in run-time.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct. I don't want to load a library but I want to load some programs dynamically. I can use the `registerModulePath`. I have to just use absolute addresses while by using `neo-app.json` it is possible to use relative addresses.